# Why does Nginx not have permissions to open this file?

Tags: nginx, permissions, selinux

I started using Nginx today for the first time, and I'm also new to command line so please be gentle.

I have a `CentOS 7` server that hosts an index.html file that I would like to access from the internet.  However I get a 403 Forbidden and Nginx seems to not have the permission to read and serve the file.  I'm trying to figure out why.

The webpage is in the home folder at `/home/Owner/web/apps/webapp/index.html`.  Here is the error logged by Nginx when I try to access that file from the web:

> [error] 9887#0: *6 "/home/Owner/web/apps/webapp/index.html" is forbidden (13: Permission denied), client: CLIENT_IP, server: my-domain.io, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "my-domain.io"

SELinux is enabled on the server. Here is the SELinux security context for the index.html file:

> [user@my-domain.io ~]# ls -lZ /home/Owner/web/apps/webapp/index.html
>
> -rw-r--r--. Owner Owner unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0 /home/Owner/web/apps/webapp/index.html

So the file is world-readable, what's the problem?  Here is the SELinux security context for the nginx process:

> [user@my-domain.io ~]# ps -auxZ | grep nginx
>
> system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0    root      9886  0.0  0.0 121508  2132 ?        Ss   19:50   0:00 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/ngin
>
> system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0    nginx     9887  0.0  0.0 121512  3604 ?        S    19:50   0:00 nginx: worker process
>
> system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0    nginx     9888  0.0  0.0 121512  3604 ?        S    19:50   0:00 nginx: worker process
>
> unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 root 9914 0.0  0.0 112712 960 pts/0 S+ 20:03   0:00 grep --color=auto nginx

I have set the following SELinux flags:

> setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect on
>
> setsebool -P httpd_enable_homedirs on

Interestingly, setting SELinux to Permissive with `setenforce 0` does not make the problem go away.  I still get a 403 forbidden.  I have tried rebooting the server to no avail.

Here is Nginx http configuration:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    listen       [::]:80;
    server_name  my-domain.io;
    root         /home/Owner/web/apps/webapp;
    
    location /api/ {
        proxy_pass "http://localhost:3333";
    }
}
```

Note the `proxypass` directives for `/api/`; that works just fine!  I can hit those paths and query the Node service running on port 3333 from the browser. The files that node executes are in a sibling directory to `index.html` parent directory.

What am I overlooking?

Comment: Check permissions of all parent directories

Comment: @AlexeyTen you were right, the user's home folder /home/Owner had access set to 700 or something like that with owner/group set to `Owner Owner`. I solved the problem by changing it to 710 and setting ownership to `Owner nginx`.  If you want credit, feel free to write up an answer.

Answer (score 0):

chcon -R -h -t httpd_sys_content_t  /home/Owner/web
and  edit  nginx.conf  user Owner

or
mv all the files  to
/usr/share/nginx/html